# Nvidia graphics drivers not installing properly

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

I didn't find a solution to my problem anywhere (even though I read countless threads about Nvidia drivers) and I am starting to think that it may be hardware problem.
I install drivers using (among others)

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

And when it is installed i check:

```
lspci | grep VGA
```

But I get identical result as when I typed it before installation, that is:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core
processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
```

Moreover, when I reboot Ubuntu, it runs in low graphics mode, but starts normally after I uninstall drivers.

I tried reinstalling the system, but it also brought no effect at all.

Comment: Did your command line install report that the nvidia-xxx.ko driver module was built (the one other than the nvidiafb.ko one)?  Did you try the --reinstall switch on your install command, since you were doing other install too?

Comment: If this is a laptop: Did you enable your graphics card in the BIOS?  If a PC: did you try the card in another PC?  Hardware problems are kind of off-topic here...

Comment: I used proprietary driveres instead of open source instead of opensource and my card works... But it still isn't displayed when typing `lspci | grep VGA` and it seems weird to me.

Answer (score -1):

After installing 'nvidia-current' did you execute 'nvidia-xconfig' to overwrite your default video configuration? If you did not it will not know to use your new nvidia configuration. Give it a try and let me know the result.